# Transactional Emails w/o Text Formatting?

Tags: email, transactional

I wanted to know if it is possible to convert all the sending transactional mails into the text format like Amazon/StickerMule does? Basically something without text formatting and just plain text so as to improve the sending time and decrease the size of the email. It gives all the information that is required and also is easily downloadable without eating up any data.

*I was assuming this is a good option, isn't it?*

Some examples:
[image]
[image]

I would be really glad if someone could assist me with that.

Comment: Can you be more clear on "like Amazon does"? Perhaps an example in your question? Do you mean plain text formatting?

Comment: Yes, some examples please.

Comment: @SanderMangel , Please have a look at the edited post above. Sorted it out.

Comment: What have you tried so far. did you take a look at the email templates in `app/locale/[]language]/template/email/...`. Here you can find all emails and change them to whatever you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The e-mail templates content is generated from the files located in app/locale/{lang}_ISO/template/email, but the templates can be overwritten from system->transactional emails.
you need to override these templates and remove the markup.
Also, the data related to ordered items/invoice items/shipping items come from `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email`. You need to copy all those files to your theme and remove the markup.

The setting that determines if a mail is sent as text or html can be found in the `config.xml` file for each email. [here is an example for `sales`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml#L1099).
You will need to create a custom module and in the `config.xml` of that custom module you need to list all e-mail tempaltes code and change the `type` tag to `text`.
Here is an example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_[Module]>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </[Namespace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <template>
            <email>
                <sales_email_order_template>
                    <type>text</type>
                </sales_email_order_template>
                <sales_email_order_guest_template>
                    <type>text</type>
                </sales_email_order_guest_template>
                .....
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

If you don't want to add all these templates in your `config.xml` you can copy the file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Template.php` to the `local` folder and change the method

```
public function isPlain()
{
    return $this->getType() == self::TYPE_TEXT;
}
```

to

```
public function isPlain()
{
    return true;
}
```

This will make all the e-mails considered as text.